# getting a traceback error when installing boto using pip

Tags: python, pip, boto

```
[root@ip-172-31-34-8 ec2-user]# sudo pip install -U boto
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line     3020, in <module>
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 616, in _build_master
return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 629, in _build_from_requirements
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 807, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==6.1.1
```

Comment: maybe your pip is old - try upgrade it first: 'sudo pip install pip -U'

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing on a fresh EC2 machine, which I guess from the first line of your code, you may not have pip installed.

For recent versions of AWS Linux AMI, you may use `easy_install` instead:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

And then:

```
sudo easy_install boto3
```

Or:

```
sudo pip install boto3
```